# Storing data in req vs res

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js

I have a middleware (in sails.js, an **express** based framework) that looks something up in a database and then stores what it found in an object, so I can use it in layouts/controllers.

Currently, I'm storing it in the `req` object, like so:

```
req.someStuff = 'Some stuff';
```

However, I just read that you can also do:

```
res.locals.someStuff = 'Some stuff';
```

What's the difference? Both manage to accomplish the same task. Thanks.

Comment: please make sure you mark this as completed if it answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

See [the docs here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.locals) .

Basically, you pass res.locals to the rendering engine (say you're using jade, ejs, etc..).  When it renders, it becomes available to the global scope, so you can just call them as named (ie. `someStuff` as opposed to `locals.someStuff`).

res.someStuff, would therefore not be available to the global scope when rendered, so cannot be accessed by whatever rendering template your using (ie. cannot be called as `someStuff`).

In a nutshell it just gives an easy way to pass something to a rendering template and have it accessible by the global scope.

An example (using ejs) would be something like

```
<% if(someStuff) { ... } %>

<!-- or even this -->
<% if(locals.someStuff) { ... } %>
```

Edit - 
I also just realized you're posting the **req**.someStuff vs **res**.someStuff.  You can read through those same docs to see the difference between those, but basically one is the incoming request object, the other is the outgoing response object.  (It's http so request-response protocol)

Comment: Oh, alright, so res.locals just give convenient variable names for layouts only. But it isn't really that much of a hassle to type, for instance, req.someStuff. I thought there might be a bigger difference. And I guess it's better to stick to req,someStuff if you will be using that in a controller too. Yeah, I had already realized req stands for request and res for response, thanks.

Comment: Yeah I think you have the general idea, but you're stating this slightly incorrectly.  If you pass something like funcName(req, resp) {..}  and continue to pass the req, resp , of course you can access both of those objects (say from controller to service layer, etc..).  But the resp is what's called/used when the page renders.  It takes whatever is on that response object and makes it available in your template file.  The req. is not (it comes from whatever was on the incoming data from the http request)

Comment: what i'm trying to say is that req and resp are fundamentally different regarding the locals field.  locals is just an easy way to keep something bound to a specific scope (res.locals - global in view templates, app.locals - scoped to your entire express application).